# Why do I have different National ideas for my Roman Empire?

Tags: crusader-kings-2, europa-universalis-iv

According to the [EU4 wiki](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Roman_Empire) I should expect the following National ideas:

[image]

But when I loaded up the game I found the following:

[image]

I understand that I should have the seven going from "Pax Romana" till "Imperium Sine Fine", but apparently I got the ideas of [Bali](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Bali).

Also, wiki states that:

> If the average technological advances in the entire realm passes a certain point, the Empire's technology group will be Western instead of Eastern after transfer to EU4.

and I was quite surprised to find out that I was in the Muslim group:

[image]

Has the above ever happened to anyone else? What are the conditions that made this happen?

The following disclaimers apply:

- it was not an ironman game
- it was actually quite an heavy-console game played for fun and giggles (the roman empire controls all the available world in CK2 by year 1000, everyone is orthodox and italian, all provinces have maxed tech)
- I converted before the endgame date
- I converted before most of the territories got included as de-jure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching around, I finally found a (partial) answer:

The empire was assigned the tag Z00 instead of the standard ROM, by reassigning the ideas in the "!_roman_ideas.txt" file to the Z00 tag (as suggested on [the paradox forums](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/imported-roman-empire-not-getting-unique-ideas.776226/#post-17412896)) solved the issue.

I still do not get why this tag problem, but I suspect it has to do with me renaming the empire to "Imperium Romanun" at the beginning.